# Kendo UI For Web - N Level Hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, hierarchy

I am looking for an elegant solution to create n-level kendo ui grid. I have a self referencing table. 
i.e

```
Id    CategoryName   ParentID
 1     cat1           0
 2     cat2           1
 3     cat3           2
```

and i want to develop a hierarchical grid using this table structure. Can any one suggest a best way to do this ? Please note that i am only using Keno For Web.( No MVC extensions ).

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @ManishKumar No. I changed my approach and used treeview to select parent nodes. Still i would like to know how we can only do this using Kendo UI Grid.